# How do I have this taken off hold?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, closed-questions

This is the name of the question: [How do I have my PCs fight one another in an arena setting but then allow them to group up for the last encounter in the arena? [on hold]](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/114878/23970)

I have added extra information but I do not see where this is alleviating the hold.

Comment: I wonder if it's worth noting that making edits doesn't automatically lift the hold; making edits does, though, automatically put the post back in front of voters' eyes to consider voting to reopen.

Answer (score 21):

I'm one of the people that voted to close your question. @GreySage's comment on your question pretty much nails it, but I will elaborate.

Honestly, I think your question is awfully close to being off-topic for the site: it strikes me as an idea generation and discussion question ("Help me come up with ideas to do X"). To me, it seems like you're asking us to help plan your session in general. Stackexchange is better at addressing specific questions, and this one is pretty open-ended. We can tell you *how* to plan your session, but we can't do it for you.

In order to re-open your question, you need to present *less,* not more. The tooltip says,

> Please clarify your **specific problem** or add additional details to highlight **exactly what you need**

The problem is that there are a lot of different questions inside your text. Here are a few:

- How do I have PCs fight each other?
- How do I have the PCs lose against a hydra but not die?
- How do I make a 4-on-2 arena battle?
- How do I prevent a split session after a PVP fight?

Each one of these is more than enough to be a separate question on its own. I suspect that some of these are answered on this site somewhere, as well. You need to pick one of these questions and focus on it, rather than asking about how to do everything all at once. If you do need answers for all of those things, you can ask multiple questions, for which there is no penalty.

Comment: I did not think it would be ideal to ask multiple questions in multiple threads, then have to go back and forth. Some of what you wrote is not accurate though . I do not need to know "How do I have the PCs lose against the Hydra and not die." I am going to be adding all the flavor text, descriptions, mechanics of fights myself but I was looking for some inspiration. Instead of putting my question on hold, why couldn't you just give me the above answer and let me elaborate if there was a question. Before the thread was put on hold, there were a few really good answers, dont be lazy, just pass

Comment: "Looking for inspiration" is not something that SE is designed for--you'd probably have better luck at a forum. Like I said, GreySage already told you what I've told you here, but you have yet to address his (or my) issues with the question. Also, mainsite answers are not a forum for discussion, but rather for answering the question at hand. Finally, I'd be glad to vote to reopen your question (and give you an answer) once you edit your question to meet the community's standards.

Comment: @mark The crux of Icyfire's answer was present in the close text. However, I can see your frustration as a new user not knowing exactly what was required, what "on hold" meant, nor how to appeal it! One issue is that Icyfire couldn't have posted this much content in a single comment, nor have good formatting to display it for you, outside of Meta's Q&A. Furthermore, comments are ephemeral; at any time they are not guaranteed to continue to exist. So if Icyfire gave you an excellent series of comments explaining all of this, it wouldn't be a permanent record for others to see, as it is here.

Comment: *I did not think it would be ideal to ask multiple questions in multiple threads, then have to go back and forth*  @Mark This isn't a forum with threads.  It's is a collection of questions with answers.  Breaking the questions up into bite sized pieces is one of the differences between this site and a discussion forum.  Put into the vernacular, it's how we roll.